# (iOS) Is there a way to retract my app submission?

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store, appstore-approval

I've just uploaded my first update to an app I've had in the app store for a while.  Unfortunately I accidentally left some debug-related code in there.  There is a UI element (a button) that triggers this code, so it is extremely likely that an app reviewer (or end user) would stumble into it.

Is there any way to rescind my app upload so I can re-upload it?  Or is my only recourse to wait until Apple rejects (or accepts, but that's somewhat unlikely) my app, then try again?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can reject your binary in iTunes connect. Manage Your Application, Go inside your project page, click on the "View details" button of the new version. you'll find a button called "Binary Details"

Finally, you should see a button called "Reject binary"

EDITED : Corrected thanks to following comment

Comment: Thanks.  I didn't notice that option since it was buried another level deep, in the "Binary Details" screen.